# Ansible, add comments to the artifacts

Tags: artifactory

Lets say, we have deployed artifacts to general repo. Is there a way to add a free text to the artifactory? I found only "Properties" but it's managed as a dictionary. Is there any free text field that we can add some helpfull info about current artifact?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the properties section, if you put some text in quotes in the value of the property, it won't be displayed as a dictionary.